# Using SVG files with monotouch

Tags: ios, svg, xamarin.ios

Trying to find a way to display/render SVG files without using the WebView object. I've found ObjC lib called SVGKit.
I'm wondering how reliable SVGKit is? Does it have monotouch bindings?
what are my options to display vector graphics on iPhone/iPad? Can this be done through using the OpenGL engine?

Comment: What did you decide to go with? SVGKit?

Comment: decided to not to SVG at all :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't personally attest to how reliable SVGKit is, but scanning [its history on GitHub](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/commits/master), it passes most of my "will I hate myself for using this project?" sanity checks:

1. It has about a dozen commits a month from several different developers,
2. It has an active issues list,
3. It has hundreds of watchers and dozens of active forks.

I don't know of any other alternatives for vector graphics on iOS. OpenGL doesn't have any built-in vector capabilities. I'm sure it could be persuaded to draw graphics that you decode some other way--it sounds like a lot of work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Codeautomat](http://www.codeautomat.com/). It can convert SVG files to Objective-C. It is different from SVGKit in the sense that it does not work in runtime; it basically compiles your SVG to code statically.